# Can't load the database result properly using codeigniter pagination class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here, can somebody please help, here's my controller.. I just want to display the database result according to the pagination set.

```
function post_paginates($offset = 0){
    $this->load->model('Users_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $limit = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/blog_ext/index.php/welcome/post_paginates/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Users_model->totalcountPost();
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['page_query_string']=true; 
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'pageno';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['offset'] = $offset;

    $posts = $this->Users_model->get_post($limit, $offset);

    $data = array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'pages' => $this->pagination->create_links()
    );

    $this->load->view('post_paginates', $data);
}
```

and here's my model

```
function get_post($limit, $offset){
    $query = $this->db->get('NEWS', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

and here's the view

```
<div id="posts">
    <?php 
    if(isset($posts)){
        foreach ($posts as $titles) {
            echo $titles->HEADLINE;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="pages">
    <?php echo $pages;?>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.. :-)

Comment: why `$config['uri_segment'] = 4;`? try with `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;`

Comment: sorry but nothing changes.. the pagination was displayed but the all the result where displayed even how many times you click on the pagination links sir. thanks btw

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the pagination. if everything is displayed than your $limit or $offset variable is wrong. Try putting actual numbers instead of them.

Comment: yeah right.. there's no offset being passed that's why.. in my base_url what is my uri segment sir(s)?

Comment: when you click on your pagination does your url change? If so can you show your url please

Comment: yes..here's my url sir..http://localhost/blog_ext/index.php/welcome/post_paginates/?pageno=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$offset = $this->input->get('pageno');
```

for your offset.